# LabVIEW PID Controller - Convert gain constants between PID algorithms

Tags: labview, pid-controller

How can I convert the PID gain constants K<sub>c</sub>, T<sub>i</sub> and T<sub>d</sub> to the alternate form K<sub>p</sub>, K<sub>i</sub> and T<sub>d</sub> in LabVIEW?

Alternatively, how can i use K<sub>c</sub>, T<sub>i</sub> and T<sub>d</sub> in LabVIEW PID control?

Comment: LabVIEW is a programming language. It sounds like you are using a particular library in that language. You are going to need to specify what library you are using for most folks to be able to help you. The names you are listing are not part of LabVIEW itself.

Comment: This is a control theory question - it sounds as if you're familiar with the 'ideal' form of the PID equation but LabVIEW's PID toolkit looks like it uses the 'parallel' form: see http://digital.ni.com/public.nsf/allkb/6E76EC47B831FAED86256E4E007347DC and http://www.ni.com/white-paper/6440/en/ . If those articles don't give you the information you need I would ask on the NI forums.

Answer (score 1):

To address your first question, [this VI](http://zone.ni.com/reference/en-XX/help/371361L-01/lvpid/pid_structure_conversion/) does exactly that.

For your second question, the LabVIEW PID VIs all use the "academic" forms (Kc, Ti, Td). So, you can just wire those values in to the "PID gains" terminal in the [PID VI.](http://zone.ni.com/reference/en-XX/help/371361L-01/lvpid/pid_vi/)